# How to pass a cmdlet or function name as a parameter in powershell

Tags: powershell

How to pass a cmdlet or function name as a parameter:

```
Write-Host "hi" | get-help <write-host>
# or
My-Custom-Function -arguments $some_arg | get-help <My-Custom-Function>
```

Comment: Specifically for `Get-Help`, you can just add `-?`: `Write-Host -?`

Comment: Thank you, Mathias, but I need to pass a cmdlet or function name as a parameter to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

The most popular way to pass parameters into a function is to build a hashtable with all of the params you want to provide.

Take this one for instance, to list all of the drives of a particular type on my computer.

```
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\cimv2 `
  -ClassName Win32_DiskDrive `
  -Filter "Caption='Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB'"
```

Kind of a lengthy command, right?  I can make a hashtable to include all of those values.

```
$params = @{
    Namespace = "root\cimv2"; 
    ClassName = "Win32_DiskDrive";
    Filter= "Caption='Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB'"
}
```

Then we go to invoke it, pay attention to the `@` character, used in place of the normal variable character, `$`.

```
Get-CimInstance @params
```

If you're asking **Why would I want to do this?**, well you see this very commonly done in functions which offer remote functionality.  A hashtable will be built and then modified based on the parameters provided or specified in the PowerShell envrionment and then handed off to an acting cmdlet to perform the actual function.

Comment: Thank you, FoxDeploy, but I need the command name - in your example "Get-CimInstance" - as a variable or parameter to pass to the next function. To use your example it should look like Get-CimInstance @params | get-help $somevar, $somevar = "Get-CimInstance"

Comment: Ah, in that case you want to use `Invoke-Expression`, which will execute the contents of a variable.  If you had `$command = "Get-Process"`, you could run `Invoke-Expression $command`, to launch that command.  Be very cautious with this approach as you are trusting user input.

Comment: A well discussed topic is that [invoke-expression is harmful](https://www.bing.com/search?q=invoke-expression+is+harmful&form=ANNTH1&refig=ee8652b0228b42aa85812fe9bd7d7612&sp=-1&pq=invoke-expression+is+harmful&sc=0-28&qs=n&sk=&cvid=ee8652b0228b42aa85812fe9bd7d7612). So, sure one could, but should you, considering? The suggestion is to use [Invoke-Command instead](https://www.bing.com/search?q=invoke-command+vs+invoke-expression&form=ANNTH1&refig=221d7ee5c28a4324a3c05e6a90d825e9&sp=-1&pq=ionvoke-command+vs+invoke-expression&sc=1-36&qs=n&sk=&cvid=221d7ee5c28a4324a3c05e6a90d825e9)